# Matrix of recurrence relation is diagonalizable iff its eigenvalues are distinct?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, diagonalization

When solving first order systems of differential equations(i.e $x'=Ax$). If $A$ here is diagonalizable, the solutions are always like $\sum e^{\lambda_i x}$ without any terms like $e^{\lambda x}x$.

When the system is actually solving some high-order linear ode (e.g. $x''+2x'+x=0$), $A$ here become the
matrix of the recurrence relation.(e.g. $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  0& 1\\
  -1&-2
\end{pmatrix}$) It seems that when the eigenvalues of characteristic polynomial are not distinct, the equation does have solutions like $e^{\lambda x}x$, is that mean $A$ here is not diagonalizable?

Comment: You have provided yourself with a concrete example of $A$. Is it diagnolizable?

Comment: Your matrix is known as a Companion Matrix.  It is probably easiest to argue that the minimal polynomial of a Companion Matrix is the same as its characteristic polynomial (up to a sign) so it is diagonalzable *iff* all eigenvalues $\in \mathbb C$ are distinct.